# How do I sort an array of Ruby on Rails Active Record objects by the end date when end data is sometimes nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Foo` model. It has many attributes. One attribute is `:end_date` and another is `:start_date`. Sometimes end date value is nil.

I want to sort this array by the `end_date` then `start_date` in descending order and all the `end_date` `nil` values should be first in order.

Thus if I have four objects like:

- object `A` has `end_date` `nil` and `start_date` Jan 2021,
- object `B` has `end_date` `nil` and `start_date` Jan 2022,
- object `C` has `end_date` of Dec 2022 and `start_date` Jan 2022,
- object `D` has `end_date` of Dec 2021 and `start_date` Jan 2021,

then the sorted order should be `[B, A, C, D]`. How would I do that?

Comment: Instead of writing this as a an very long and very hard to read paragraph use code blocks to show us an example of the data in the database and what you expect to get as a result. Simple ASCII tables are good way to do this.  You should also at least attempt to solve this task so that we have a starting point and don't have to write everything from scratch. Help us help you.

Comment: But generally speaking you would use order together with a SQL case statement. Don't sort arrays. Let the DB do the work. https://www.thd.codes/posts/how-to-write-order-by-case-query-with-arel/

Comment: Thanks for the edit Holger - point taken. Unfortunately I can't do a rewrite of the code. I'm tasked with editing a specific line. The array is already there, it just needs to be sorted. I started with `.sort_by(&:end_date)` and hit the ArgumentError: comparison of Date with nil failed error.

Comment: What DB are you using? With PostgreSQL you can do `Foo.order('end_date DESC NULL FIRST, start_date DESC')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo_array.sort_by { |f| [f.end_date.nil? ? 0 : 1, f.end_date.to_i, f.start_date.to_i] }.reverse
```

- The nil ternary will ensure those are first
- converting end_date / start_date to integers will ensure their ordering
- Then calling reverse will give you descending order

Comment: If you feel this (or any of the answers) solved your problem, would you be so kind as to accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you can execute a SQL query, the following should work for you.

```rb
Foo.order('start_date IS NOT NULL, start_date DESC')
```

If on the other hand you already have the materialized array, you can do the following.

```rb
arr = Array of Foos
arr.sort_by { |a, b| a.start_date && b.start_date ? a.start_date <=> b.start_date : a.start_date ? 1 : -1 }
```

Repeat the same process for end_date

Answer (score 0):

Single pass using #sort

a) using sort with block

```
# Using sort method
sorted = entries.sort do |a,b|
  # 1, 0 , -1 or nil
  comparison_result = a.end_date <=> b.end_date

  if comparison_result.nil?
    # nil follows a date
    a.end_date.nil? ? 1 : -1
  elsif comparison_result.zero?
    # end_dates are equal, compare start_dates instead
    a.start_date <=> b.start_date
  else
      comparison_result
  end.* -1 # descending order
end
```

b) add custom compare method to your model or module then do

```
sorted = entries.sort do |a,b|
    a.compare_using_dates b
end

class Foo
  def compare_using_dates(other)
    comparison_result = end_date <=> other.end_date

    # nil result means one of the records has a nil end_date, so the end_dates are not equal
    if comparison_result.nil?
      end_date.nil? ? 1 : -1
    elsif comparison_result.zero?
      # end_dates are equal, compare start_dates instead
      start_date <=> other.start_date
    else
      comparison_result
    end.* -1
  end
end
```